# Eclipse loads same editor panel twice

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class source (or other file) open in the Eclipse edit (say Foo.java) and do a search for (say) "Foo" which returns a line in the Search window. When I click on this it loads a second instance of the source, both called "Foo.java" and both mapped onto the same file. If I try, say, autocompletion on the first window it behaves normally but on the second it gives "This compilation unit is not on the path of a Java project".

I am using

```
Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415
```

EDIT:

- Why does this happen?
- Why is one instance on the build path and the other is not?
- How can I prevent two
  windows appearing?

Comment: @Favonius thanks - have added specific questions

Comment: Can't recreate the problem on my machine. I am using `Helios` but the build is different. `Version: Helios Service Release 1` and 
`Build id: 20100917-0705`.

Comment: @Favonius then maybe I just have to upgrade yet again :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a clear answer other than, probably, to reinstall Eclipse